# What is $\nabla Au$ for $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $u:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $u:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. How can we compute $\nabla Au$? I assume we need to apply some kind of product rule, but I wasn't able to figure out how exactly.

Comment: Taking the gradient with respect to what, $u$?

Comment: @Ian No, with respect to $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Oh, now I see, $A$ is a matrix-valued function of space and $u$ is a...scalar-valued function of space? Did you mean for $u$ to be vector-valued?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $Au : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ since $A$ is a matrix and $u$ is a scalar.  Then the derivative is really a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.  You can compute it in terms of partials:
$$
D(Au)(x) h = \sum_{i=1}^n \partial_i(Au)(x) h_i
$$ 
where $h\in \mathbb{R}^n$.  Reinterpreting this as a gradient, we have that the compenents are $\partial_i(A u)(x)$, and for this we may compute
$$
\partial_i (A_{jk}(x) u(x)) = \partial_i A_{jk}(x) u(x) + A_{jk}(x) \partial_i u(x)
$$
for each $j,k =1,\dotsc,n$ by using the usual product rule.

Comment: So, if I am not mistaken, the operation $\nabla A u$, takes a 2-rank tensor and returns a 3-rank tensor, right?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to think about it.  The three indices you have come from the derivative (the $i$ above) and the two components of the matrix ($j,k$ above).

Comment: Unfortunately, I've found out, that this wasn't the question I intended to ask. Maybe you can answer the right one too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340543/what-is-nabla-cdot-a-nabla-u-for-a-in-c1-mathbbrn-to-mathbbrn-times

Comment: Sure, it's basically the same sort of argument.  Check for the answer on your other question.