# What is $\nabla\cdot A\nabla u$ for $A\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n})$ and $u\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $A\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n})$ and $u\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R})$. How can we compute $\nabla\cdot A\nabla u$? I assume we need to apply some kind of product rule, but I wasn't able to figure out how exactly.

Comment: How are you using $\nabla$ and $\nabla\cdot$? I assume $\nabla u$ is a matrix?

Comment: @snarski No, $u$ is a scalar-valued function. $\nabla\cdot f$ is the formal scalarproduct of $$\nabla=(\partial_1,\ldots,\partial_n)^T$$ and $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Answer (score 1):

We have the mappings $\nabla u : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, so $A \nabla u : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is given by $(A\nabla u)_i(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}(x) \partial_j u(x)$.

Now you want to compute $\nabla \cdot A \nabla u$, which is then given by 
$$
\nabla \cdot (A \nabla u)(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \partial_i (A\nabla u)_i(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\partial_i [A_{ij}(x) \partial_j u(x)] \\= \sum_{i,j=1}^n [A_{ij}(x) \partial_i \partial_j u(x) + \partial_i A_{ij} \partial_j u(x) ].
$$
In the last equality we just used the normal product rule.